# identification of species of this bird

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Hi I saw this bird near my school canteen in Singapore in Spring. Can anyone identify the species of this bird? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you add the geographic location where it was found and the time of year?

Comment: @kmm: Singapore, and recently, a few days ago.

Comment: I would say that it would be a subspecies of a raven or a crow but it is hard to identify seeing that the bird has been through a disease or met with an accident..

Comment: This question may be difficult, but it isn't too broad. In fact, I can't imagine a narrower question than "Which species is this animal?". I think that the question should be reopened.